# why turn infinity when sending request HTTP GET|POST laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, request

I am created new laravel project

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel/eagle_project_v2
```

I istalled guzzle to make http request

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

then add this root after created a freelancer Model and controller

```
Route::apiResource('/freelancers','FreelancersController');
```

and I want to make request from my controller, but when I call it, **turn ininitly without response**

-I tried many different url -

```
$guzzle = new Client;        
        $result = $guzzle->post('my_url_I_tried_many_URL', [
            'form_params' => [
                'key' => 'value'
            ]
        ]);
        return result;
```

and I tried this without using any library and it make the same error
Although the code is work well when I try it outside laravel (in separate project -only with php-)

Comment: Are you trying to get your controller to call a resource in the same application? If so, what is the purpose?

Comment: Also can you post all your routing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but your `guzzle` post call is to `api/freelancers`.

`Route::apiResources()` does not specify that it will use `api/` as a prefix. Its purpose is to remove calls to endpoints which are intended to return html (such as `create` and `edit` routes).

Unless you specify `api` as a **prefix** to your routes, calls to `api` may not be resolved:

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('/freelancers','FreelancersController');
});
```

Comment: What local server are you using to host your application?